# Angular 2+ and Observables: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

Tags: json, asynchronous, drop-down-menu, angular, angular2-observables

EDIT: Updated Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fQ7P9KPjMxb5NAhccYIq?p=preview

this part works:

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of entries | async">
  Label: {{ entry.label }}<br>
  Value: {{ entry.value }}
</div>
```

but I've problems with the select box, the error message is:

**Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'**

**The whole Component:**

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgFor} from '@angular/common';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `

  <select [(ngModel)]="selectValue" name="selectValue">
    <option *ngFor="let entry of entries | async" 
    [value]="entry.value">{{entry.label}}</option>
  </select>

    <div *ngFor="let entry of entries | async">
      Label: {{ entry.label }}<br>
      Value: {{ entry.value }}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgFor]
})
export class App {

  entries: any = {};
  selectValue:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.entries = this._http.get("./data.json")
                            .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**and data.json**

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 0,
    "label": "l1",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 0,
    "label": "l2",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 0,
    "label": "l3",
    "value": 3    
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you using RC5 or are you only using the Angular 2 template in Plunkr?

Comment: is there a difference? If yes, what should I change?

Comment: it should be `[(ngModel)]` but this is not the main reason

Comment: Thank you, I've updated both, question and plunkr

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**>= RC.5**

The `FormsModule` needs to be imported to make `ngModel` available

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule /* or CommonModule */, 
  FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  ...
)}
class SomeModule {}
```

**<= RC.4**

In `config.js` add

```
'@angular/forms': {
  main: 'bundles/forms.umd.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

in `main.ts` add

```
import {provideForms, disableDeprecatedForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(App, [disableDeprecatedForms(),provideForms()])
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zU3B3VZvuf8YVa7yMqQ9?p=preview)

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html

Comment: all these steps above are already done, it must be an another -observables-related - problem

Comment: That's what I had to change in your Plunker to make it work.

Comment: But I don't use RC5, it is enough, if it works with RC4

Comment: I wasn't sure from the comments below your question. What I posted should work the same in RC.4. In RC.5 you'll get deprecated warnings with the code from my answer (see also in my Plunker).

Comment: All I get for the select box (inspected in chrome) is: `<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->`

Comment: If you use objects as values you need to use `[ngValue]=...´ instead of `[value]=...`. On `<select>` `[value]=...` only works with string values.

Comment: Without bindings it also works with value: http://plnkr.co/edit/fQ7P9KPjMxb5NAhccYIq?p=preview  As far as I add [(ngModel)] I have troubles. Maybe my selectValue is not compatible with the data delivered? Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes exactly, what did you change?

Comment: The changes listed in my answer and I added `name="x"` to the `<select>` which seems to be required for standalone elements using `ngModel` in the new forms module. I think that was all.

Comment: I had already add a name for select before: http://plnkr.co/edit/fQ7P9KPjMxb5NAhccYIq  but it did not work. (the name was "selectValue". Did you change something in the configuration? Or I may not use as select name "selectValue"? I am really confused,..

Comment: Again, yes. That what I posted in my answer. Your Plunker again doesn't contain these things.

Comment: I just want to point out that a name attribute on select elements *isn't necessary*, at least in RC5. I have a local project here and ngModel works as expected without it. Furthermore, in all of the Plunkers in this thread, as long as the Forms package is correctly imported, the select drop down works just the same with or without a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

In  app.modules.ts after

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

put:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And then in

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule
 ],
```

insert the FormsModule something like:

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule
 ],
```

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me in my testing suite, despite the fact that I'd already imported `FormsModule` in my component's `*.module.ts` file.

In my `*.component.spec.ts` file, I needed to add both `FormsModule` *and* `ReactiveFormsModule` to the imports list in `configureTestingModule`:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ 
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ....],
    providers: [MyComponent, ...],
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

This fixed my case.

Comment: Noticed that providers might be services as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your `app.module.ts` file.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And,

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      FormsModule,
      ...
   ]})
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error is caused because you haven't imported FormsModule,ngModel is present in the FormsModule package so,to get rid of this error add `import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'` and add FormsModule in imports in app.module.ts class.

Answer (score -1):

do the following you have to use `[ngValue]` instead of `[val]`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectValue">
    <option *ngFor="let entry of entries | async" 
        [ngValue]="entry.value">{{entry.label}}
    </option>
</select>
```