# Angular 2 template driven form with ngFor inputs

Tags: forms, angular, ngfor

Is it possible to create input fields with a ngFor in a template driven form and use something like #name="ngModel" to be able to use name.valid in another tag?

Right now we have a dynamic list of products with a quantity field and a add to cart button in a table. I want to make the whole thing a form with a add all button at the end like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="item in items">
        <input name="product-{{item.id}}"
               [(ngModel)]="item.qty"
               #????="ngModel"
               validateQuantity>
        <button (click)="addItemToCart(item)"
                [disabled]="!????.valid">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addAll()"
            [disabled]="!form.valid">Add all</button>
</form>
```

But how can i generate a new variable name per row for the ngModel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+ and Observables: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983766/angular-2-and-observables-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-prope)

Comment: @rene It's definitively a similar question but on different parts, I didn't know the syntax to make my template work while that question had the correct syntax but was missing a module.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's no need for this, just do it like this:

```html
<form #form="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="item in items">
        <input name="product-{{item.id}}"
               [(ngModel)]="item.qty"
               validateQuantity
               #qtyInput>
        <button (click)="addItemToCart(item)"
                [disabled]="!qtyInput.valid">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addAll()"
            [disabled]="!form.valid">Add all</button>
</form>
```

Its Angular's part here. :)

Comment: Wait what? I tried this and it didnt work but suddenly it does, must have made some typo or other mistake.. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: I get error : If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions. when I use name={{item.name}}. but when i add string first of attr, it works!!! >> name="someTxt{{item.name}}" !!!! but i need name equal with item.name value. can you help me??

Answer (score 2):

The **mxii** answer works as expected for form items dynamically created by `ngFor`, but if you're not going to use `ngForm`, and you're iterating over a list of items that have an independent entity (like a list of comments, and the user should be able to reply each comment) you can use [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) which give you the ability to get and work with the Input element easily.

Here is how you can do it:

```
// Your template
<div *ngFor="item in items">
  <!-- Your input -->
  <input #itemInput type="number">

  <button (click)="addItemToCart(itemInput.value)"
          [disabled]="!itemInput.value">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

It gives a reference to the variable assigned to the input field, and here in the example above we passed `itemInput.value` which will be the value of the input field; There might be cases that you need a reference to the input field (let's say you're going to remove its value when you got the data), you can just pass the `itemInput` and which is a type of `HTMLInputElement` and access its data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add FormModule to your app.module.ts to get 2-way-binding working, at least in newer versions of angular

[Angular 4 - "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)