# How to get input value from input type="text" in loop ngFor

Tags: angular

I have problem about getting value from input type="text" in ngFor while I bind it with [(ngModel)] all of it has same value how can I bind all input in ngFor ?

html

```
<button (click)="saveFeature()" type="button">save</button>

<input class="form-control" type="text" />
<button (click)="addFeature()" type="button">Add</button>

<div *ngFor="let inputservice of servicesfeature_id; let i=index">
  <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="listServiceFeature" type="text" />
  <button (click)="RemoveFeature(i)" type="button">Remove</button>
</div>
```

component

```
servicesfeature_id: any = [];
servicesfeature_length: number = 0;
listServiceFeature: any = [];
servicefeature_name: string;

saveFeature(): void {
  console.log(this.listServiceFeature);
}

addFeature(): void {
  this.servicesfeature_id.push('service' + this.servicesfeature_length);
  this.servicesfeature_length += 1;
}

RemoveFeature(index): void {
  this.servicesfeature_length -= 1;
  this.servicesfeature_id.splice(index, 1);
}
```

here is code [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/IlA89Vo2sxBY0FPLe2yb?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+ and Observables: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983766/angular-2-and-observables-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-prope)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand this, you want to have the inputs bind to members of the `listServiceFeature` array. Is that right? If that's what you want to do, you can bind directly to the array members using the index:

```
  <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="listServiceFeature[i]" type="text" />
```

Now if you add some text to the added inputs and hit save you get the whole array on the console.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah did you really just down vote this three year old question with only "it wasn't work?" If you want help  or want to clarify something, leave a more meaning full comment. It clearly worked for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, if you are using a newer version of angular (Angular 4) you have to import FormModule

[Angular 4 - "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)