# Angular error: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I'm using Angular 4 and I am getting an error in the console:

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to add `FormsModule` to `imports: []` of the module where you use `ngModel`. Otherwise post your code.

Comment: I can't thinking that *all* new Angular 2 & 4 developers are going to hit this exact issue (myself included).  When was the last time you used Angular and *didn't* want to use ngModel somewhere ?  I don't understand why FormsModule isn't just included by default....

Comment: For what it's worth, I encountered this error in IONIC-4 ( 4.11.0 ) when working with Forms Validation.  If I do nothing else except add formControlName="myControl" to any <ion-input> anywhere in the form, I get the ngModel binding error message. Alternate properties, like formControlName1="myControl" do not cause this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 936, accepted):

In order to use two-way data binding for form inputs you need to import the **`FormsModule`** package in your Angular module.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ]
```

---

**EDIT**

Since there are lot of duplicate questions with the same problem, I am enhancing this answer.

There are two possible reasons

- Missing **`FormsModule`**, hence Add this to your Module,

  ```
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  @NgModule({
      imports: [
          FormsModule      
      ]
  ```
- Check the syntax/spelling of `[(ngModel)]` in the input tag

Comment: What is the relation between ngModel and FormsModule? However this is not working for me.

Comment: FormsModule provides additional directives on form's elements, including input, select, etc. That's why it's required. Don't forget to import FormsModule in the same module which declares your components containing form element bindings.

Comment: What do we do if we're using this in a component ts file?

Comment: you should not import inside component.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan what if I have a template in my Component that uses ng-model in some form element?

Comment: then also it should be the same

Comment: The same as what?

Comment: the answer above, i guess you are refering [(ngModel)] right? or ng-model?

Comment: @Sajeetharan.. Hello Sajeetharan .. can you please help me out with this question......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535102/deleting-selected-items-from-mat-list-not-working-in-angular-2-using-angular-mat/49541113#49541113

Comment: What if I have 2+ `child.module.ts`, should I import `FormModule` separately in each child module or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: `ngModal` dammit

Comment: After running into this in two earlier projects you'd think I'd remember this by now. One of those things you do once per project and forget all about..

Comment: I am facing similar issues. Here is my code:                          

File: server.component.ts                                                         
<p>
    <input 
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="updatedServerName">
</p> 

File:app.module.ts

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528680/md-autocomplete-not-found-passing-the-old-values-when-we-submit-the-form

Comment: it's 2019 and we are at Angular 8 and still have these problems... when do they want to fix it?!

Comment: I do have the same problem, I have the Angular v9 it happens to me.
Your answer doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Importing component in the module.ts file solved my problem. I forgot to add component registration.

P.s: Importing FormModule in module.ts is must.

Comment: "Check the syntax/spelling of [(ngModel)] in the input tag" This is exactly the mistake I made. Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 40):

This is a right answer.
you need to import 'FormsModule'

first in app.module.ts

**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule  } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**
second in app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Best regards and hope will be helpful.

Comment: Is the second step, altering *app.component.ts* necessary?

Answer (score 18):

Your **`ngModel`** is not working because it's not a part of your **`NgModule`** yet.

You have to tell the **`NgModule`** that you have authority to use **`ngModel`** throughout your app, You can do it by adding **`FormsModule`** into your **`app.module.ts`** -> **`imports`**-> **`[]`**.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({

   imports: [ FormsModule ],       // HERE

   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
 })
```

Comment: Well, it depends: if your Angular app consists of more than just the root app module, you might want to import the FormsModule in selected modules only.

Answer (score 13):

All the above mentioned solutions to the problem are correct.
But if you are using lazy loading, `FormsModule` needs to be imported in the child module which has forms in it. Adding it in `app.module.ts` won't help.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this error when testing my Angular 6 App with Karma/Jasmine.  I had already imported `FormsModule` in my top-level module.  But when I added a new component that used `[(ngModel)]` my tests began failing.  In this case, I needed to import `FormsModule` in my `TestBed` `TestingModule`.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
      RegisterComponent
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

In `app.module.ts` add this:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [FormsModule],
})
```

Comment: What additional value does this answer add to the existing answers?

Comment: doesnt add any value to the answer and the format of the code is wrong. Confusing for begineer.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Add `FormsModule` in your `NgModule` imports (hence `ngModel` is a part of `FormsModule`).

> **Note** it can be `AppModule` or **feature module** loaded lazily via lazy loading.

```
imports: [
   ...,
   FormsModule,
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should verify following things if the two way binding does not work.

> In html the ngModel should be called this way. **There is no dependency on other attribute of the input element**

`<input [(ngModel)]="inputText">`

> Make Sure FormsModule is imported into the modules file `app.modules.ts`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent // suppose, this is the component in which you are trying to use two ay binding
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        // other modules
],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Make sure the component in which you are trying to use ngModel for two way binding is added in the declarations of the. *Code added in the previous point #2*

*This is everything that you need to do to make the two way binding using ngModel work, this is validated up to angular 9*

Comment: In my case, I had not added the HomeComponent. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

After spending hours on this issue found solution [here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/187)

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule,
         ReactiveFormsModule      
    ]
})
```

Comment: No need to import ReactiveFormsModule. Only FormsModule is required.

Answer (score 3):

The Answer for me was wrong spelling of `ngModel`. I had it written like this : `ngModule` while it should be `ngModel`.

All other attempts obviously failed to resolve the error for me.

Comment: Ya, This happened to me as well... Model != Module Why does that not go in my brain!

Answer (score 3):

[image]I tried all the thing that are mentioned above, but still it is not working.

but finally I found the issue in Angular site.Try to import formModule in module.ts thats it. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

> ngModel in module level

The code is same as the above

Answer (score 2):

Update with *Angular 7.x.x*, encounter the same issue in one of my **modules**.

If it lies in your independent module, add these extra modules:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule], // the order can be random now;
  ...
})
```

If it lies in your `app.module.ts`, add these modules:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ FormsModule, BrowserModule ], // order can be random now
  ...
})
```

A simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) to prove the case.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I added the missing import, which was the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use two-way data binding for form inputs you need to import theFormsModule package in your Angular module. For more info see the Angular 2 official tutorial here and the official documentation for forms

in the app.module.ts add below lines :

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I misspelled , I was referring as ngmodel istead of ng**M**odel :) Hope It helps!

Expected  - [(ngModel)]
Actual    - [(ngmodel)]

Answer (score 1):

import form module in app.module.ts.

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule     //Add here form  module
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

In html:

```
<input type="text" name="last_name" [(ngModel)]="last_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control">
```

Comment: I used form in html, and imported forms module in app.madule.ts like-  import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms', and add that FormsModule in imports.

Answer (score 1):

in angular 7, you have to import "ReactiveFormsModule".

`import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';`

I solved this issue by this import.It would help you.

Comment: for some strange reason it only worked with `ReactiveFormsModule` & without `FormsModule` (angular 13)

Answer (score 0):

first import FormsModule and then use ngModel in your component.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
 imports: [ 
            FormsModule  
          ];
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)] ="usertext" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If even after importing the formsmodule the problem persists, check that your Input **does not have a "name" attribute  with value equal to another** input on page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, during a lazy-loading conversion of my application I had incorrectly imported the `RoutingModule` instead of my `ComponentModule` inside `app-routing.module.ts`