# ngModel not working in Angular4

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am learning Angular 4 from the [official site](https://angular.io) and I came to the part with [2-way data binding through **ngModel**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#import-the-formsmodule). However, my app stops working as soon as I add [(ngModel)] to my component template, even though the FormsModule is imported in the module.ts file. The component does not load.
I am using Visual Studio Code.
This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    export class Hero {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }



    @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      template: `
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>Id:</label> {{hero.id}} </div>
      <div>name:<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" type="text"></div>
      `,
      styles:[`
        .selected{
          transition: padding 0.3s;
          color: mediumseagreen;
        }
      `]
    })

    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Tour Of Heroes';

     hero:Hero = {
       id:1,
       name:"Mr. Invisible"
     };
    }
```

This is app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppComponent, Hero } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FormsModule
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

The AppComponent is not loaded and just shows

Loading...

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Can you please show the error message and some code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I just had the same error. The page just stays blank. No errors on the command line. In the Javascript console (in Chrome), it says "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Comment: for anyone else who comes here because of this error: the tutorial explains the error and how to fix it. You just need to continue with the tutorial to fix this error.

Comment: Check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-error-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-inpu/61123200#61123200

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppComponent, Hero } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent

      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule  // forms module should be in imports not in declarations
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: @Michael i guess there is comment on that line of the code right , Forms Module Import should fix it .

Answer (score 27):

As others pointed out, it is important to import the `FormsModule` (e.g. in your `app.module.ts` file.) In this specific question, it was missing in the import section.

But I added this answer to warn you about something else, which I run into from time to time.

If you just use `ngModel` standalone, without a form somewhere, you don't have to specify a `name` for the input.

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="model.something">
```

**But when you do use it in a form, the `name` attribute becomes mandatory !**

```
<form>
  <input ... name="something" [(ngModel)]="model.something">
</form>
```

It's actually in the docs:

> When using the ngModel within  tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.

If you miss it, it won't show any errors at all, it just won't work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `name` attribute!

Answer (score 9):

In addition of `FormsModule` needed in the `imports` section of the module declaration, you have to use a `form` tag, or a `ngForm` directive to enable the `ngModel` functionalities.

Withoutou can also use a standalone control to use `ngModel`like this :

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="variable" #ctrl="ngModel" >
```

Source :[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: Great answer! much better than the others, which are only code.

Answer (score 3):

```
// add the import in module and add FormModule in import:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   // add FormModule in import
    FormsModule
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then at `@NgModule(){imports:[FormsModule]}` with other staff

Answer (score 0):

two-way binding

inside app.module.ts

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
FormsModule
],

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Be careful that if you use [(ngModel)] in a component that exists in your custom module, you must add this line to your custom.module not app.module.

In this case by Adding this line to app.module nothing change and you still see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; in app-routing.module.ts file.
Make sure
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; is available in app.module.ts

imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
AppRoutingModule]

Answer (score 0):

For those which are still having this problem. If an [(ngModel)] attribute is applied on a html tag within the  tag, ngModel will not behave like it should.

Get rid of any tags within a form tag to retrieve the original behaviour of ngModel.