# input box value not printed

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Code:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="goalStatusList;" >
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let goalStatus of goalStatusList">
      <th>{{goalStatus.goalStatusId}}</th>
      <td><div *ngIf="!(goalStatus.editorEnabled)">
{{goalStatus.goalStatusName}}
<md-icon (click)="goalStatus.editorEnabled=true;">mode_edit</md-icon></div>
  <div *ngIf="(goalStatus.editorEnabled)" ><md-input-container><input mdInput value="goalStatus.goalStatusName" #goalName></md-input-container><md-icon (click)="modifyGoal()" style="color:green;font:bold;" >done</md-icon><md-icon (click)="goalStatus.editorEnabled=false" style="color:red;font:bold;" >clear</md-icon></div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The mdInput field above does not print the goalStatusName value. Instead it simply prints `goalStatus.goalStatusName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here

Your ngIf should be without brackets,

```
<td><div *ngIf="!goalStatus.editorEnabled">
```

and use expression in case of value

```
<input mdInput value="{{goalStatus.goalStatusName}}" #goalName>
```

Comment: How do I implement two-way binding in here?

Comment: you should use ngModel

Comment: Tried. Getting error: `Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("dit</md-icon></div>`. My code: `<md-input-container><input mdInput ng-model="{{row.goalStatusName}}" #goalName></md-input-container>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/43298039#43298039

Comment: Solved: `<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="row.goalStatusName" #goalName>`

Comment: I did:(. One more... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022971/set-button-to-appear-on-hover

Comment: @RahulSingh Both nice answers. Thnx for help.

Comment: @KrishnakantSarda now you should be able to do

Comment: There is nothi g wrong with OP's `*ngIf`. Also, using `[value]="row.goalStatusName"` also works.