# set button to appear on hover

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have a button in angular 4 material table cell that I'd like to appear only when hover on table row:

```
<md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" contenteditable='false' > 
        <div *ngIf="!row.editorEnabled" >{{row.goalStatusName}}
            <button md-icon-button><md-icon (click)="row.editorEnabled=true;" mdTooltip="Edit">mode_edit</md-icon></button>
          </div>
</md-cell>
```

How do I achieve this?

Update:
Entire code:

```
<md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" contenteditable='false' > 
        <div *ngIf="!row.editorEnabled" >{{row.goalStatusName}}
            <button md-icon-button><md-icon (click)="row.editorEnabled=true;" class="editButton" mdTooltip="Edit">mode_edit</md-icon></button>
          </div>
        <div *ngIf="row.editorEnabled" >
          <md-input-container><input mdInput [(ngModel)]="row.goalStatusName" #goalName></md-input-container>
            <button md-icon-button>
              <md-icon (click)="modifyGoal(row.goalStatusId,row.goalStatusName)" mdTooltip="Save" style="color:green;font:bold;" >done</md-icon>
            </button>
            <button md-icon-button>
              <md-icon (click)="row.editorEnabled=false" mdTooltip="Cancel" style="color:red;font:bold;" >clear</md-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
    </md-cell>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
button{ display:none}
md-cell:hover{

  button{
     display:block
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, how do I bring focus to another input element in md-cell on button click?

Comment: put a #elem on the input and then (click)="row.editorEnabled=true; elem.focus()"

Comment: I am using *ngFor and all input elements would have same id then

Comment: Will have to use some jquery here I guess

Comment: Use ViewChildred and then get the input you want

Comment: no, you can use ViewChildren, get all the inputs, pass some index from your template inside a function and then get it and call `.focus()`

Answer (score 4):

```
.editButton{ visibility: hidden}
md-cell:hover .editButton{
visibility: visible;
}
```

This worked!