# ngModel does not work in the input field

Tags: angular

I'm just starting with Angular and trying a simple thing. Angular should update DOM when I type a name in the input field. However when I use these brackets [] like [(ngModel)] not only does it not work, but the input field disappears from the DOM. Without these [] brackets it does not work either. Please help

app.component.html file

```
 input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">
 <p>{{ name }}</p>
```

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: '.app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
name = '';
}
```

Comment: Check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-error-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-inpu/61123200#61123200

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use `ngModel` you should firstly import it.

In the app.module.ts, just add:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Comment: OP's case is not working even if ngModel is not used at all

Answer (score 3):

1) The < symbol is missing from the input tag

2) The property "name" has to be made as public in order to access that in the view

Comment: Thank you, there is < in my code just missed it here in the question
How can I make name public?

Comment: public name : string = ''     (there's single quote at end)

Answer (score 2):

You probably asking for "How Binding works"

(`[(ngModel)]`) = Also called banana in the box

- If you are using only `[]` it means you are just binding value which is called attribute binding
- If you are using only `()` It means it is just event binding and fire event on change,click etc .

In case you are using both, it means `two-way binding`  in Angular. it will Update the value into DOM as well as your controller side.