# I am getting error in binding ngModel in input

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

While binding ngModel to the input I am finding the following error -

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<div>
<span> Select : </span>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="all" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="SelectRadioButtonValue" (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged()"  />
<span> {{"All: " "): ng:///AppModule/EmpCountComponent.html@2:47
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (">
<span> {{"male: " + '(' + male + ')' }} </span>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="female" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="SelectRadioButtonValue"   (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged()" />
<span> {{"Female"): ng:///AppModule/EmpCountComponent.html@6:50
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `[(ngModel)]` you should import `FormsModule` into your `AppModule`:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```