# Sharing data between components using Service

Tags: angular, angular6

After a user selects a Navigation item from a drop-down list, the corresponding details of the Navigation item should be populated using textboxes.

I have a navigation component that's used to create the drop-down list and a navigation-detail component to populate the textboxes.  For now, I just want to show one of the properties of the navigation in the navigation-detail component.  I'm using a service to pass the navigation chosen from the drop-down list to the navigation-detail component.

In the ngAfterViewInit method of navigation-detail.component.ts, I can log to the console any of the properties of the navigation item.  However, when I try the same on navigation-detail.component.html, the following error is shown:

Cannot read property 'NavName' of undefined.

Here is the code:

navigation.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="navigations" >
  <mat-option (click)="sendChangedNav(nav)" *ngFor="let nav of navigations" [value]="nav.Id">
    {{nav.NavName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<app-navigation-detail></app-navigation-detail>
```

navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../navigation.service';
import { INavigation } from '../INavigation';
import { ShareAppIDService } from '../share-app-id.service';
import { ShareNavigationService } from '../share-navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  navigations: Array<INavigation>;

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService, private shareAppIdService: ShareAppIDService,
    private sharedNavService: ShareNavigationService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.shareAppIdService.appIdChanged.subscribe((appId) => {
      this.navigationService
        .getNavigations(appId)
        .subscribe(data => {this.navigations = data; });
        console.log(appId);
    });
  }

  sendChangedNav(nav) {
    this.sharedNavService.changeNavigation(nav);
  }
}
```

navigation-detail.component.html

```
{{navigation.NavName}}
```

navigation-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValueTransformer } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import { INavigation } from '../INavigation';
import { ShareNavigationService } from '../share-navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-detail',
  templateUrl: './navigation-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-detail.component.css']
})
export class NavigationDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  navigation: INavigation;

  constructor(private sharedNavService: ShareNavigationService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sharedNavService.navigationChanged.subscribe((navigation) => {
      this.navigation = navigation;
      console.log('navigation detail id is: ' + navigation.NavPageURL);
    });
  }

}
```

shared-navigation.component.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { INavigation } from './INavigation';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareNavigationService {

  constructor() { }

  private navigation = new Subject<INavigation>();
  public navigationChanged = this.navigation.asObservable();

  public changeNavigation(value) {
    this.navigation.next(value);
    console.log('navigation from changeNavigation service is ' + value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats because `navigation` will be undefined until `subscription` kicks in in navigation-detail-component. Try using safe navigation in the HTML `{{navigation?.NavName}}`

Comment: That worked. In navigation-detail.component.html, I changed the code to: <input type="text" name="navigationName" [(NgModel)]="navigation.NavName" >.  I'm getting an error can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `NgModel`, use `ngModel` and import `FormsModule` in your app module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Ashish use safe navigation operator to handle the undefined error,

**`{{navigation?.NavName}}`**

related to the second issue, **`NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`**
you need to add **`FormsModule`** in your **`app.module.ts`** imports.

check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/43298039#43298039)**.