# How can we call two different function for a dropdown in HTML/Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I coded a dropdown with two option inside: english and french.
But for each option I need to call a different function. 
My code is in HTML :

```
 <select (click)="myFuncEnglish()">
    <option value="EN">English</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

And for Angular is:

```
myFuncEnglish() {
    console.log('function called is english');
  }`
```

Can you help me please to know how can I code different function for the different options, and to display when I click on french "function called is french", and when I click on english "function called is english".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you don't need to call two functions.
You need to pass the selected value as the function argument and check the value in the function body to console log your message.

### HTML

```
<select (ngModelChange)="myFuncEnglish($event)"  [(ngModel)]="lang">
    <option value="EN">English</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

## Component

```
myFuncEnglish(lang) {
    if(lang === 'FR'){
      console.log('function called is french');
    } else {
      console.log('function called is english');
    }
}
```

See a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-angular-onchange)

Comment: ngModel is not a property of select so it does not work for me.

Comment: You can have a ngModel for you ```select``` tag

Comment: ngModel requires the forms model to be imported into your module.

Comment: it displays this on my computer Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("le {male} female {female} other {other}}}}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Answer (score 0):

Do it onchange insted, on Angular i think it is `ng-change="funcEnglish()"`

Then on `funcEnglish` validate the `item.value` to know you what to do.

```js
function funcEnglish(item) {
    console.log('function called is '+ item.value);
  }
```

```html
 <select onchange="funcEnglish(this)">
    <option value="Empty">None</option>
    <option value="EN">English</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it displays nothing without errors and I don't know why, and I used ng-charge

Comment: i really dont know Angular  very much but i think that you should remove function and have only `funcEnglish` i think.

Comment: yes It's how I coded with your help but It still doesn't work

Comment: Really cant help you with that. i have never worked with Angular before. but i think that there is something wrong with your component. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange to know how ng-change work

Answer (score 0):

Another way is not using ngModel just use *change* event.

**HTML**

```
<select (change)="myFuncEnglish($event)">
    <option value="EN">English</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
</select>
```

**Typescript**

```
myFuncEnglish(event: any) {
    if(event.value === 'FR'){
      console.log('function called is french');
    } else {
      console.log('function called is english');
    }
}
```