# Data Binding with [ngModel] not working Angular 6

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I just created an empty `Angular` project on `IntelliJ`, I'm trying to bind a textbox to an object's member. My object stays `undefined` or whatever I assign to it inside `OnInit`. I included `FormsModule` in the `app.module.ts` and I can't get it to work.
This is my `app.component.html` file:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" [ngModel]="person.name">
    <button (click)="save()">save</button>
</form>
```

This is `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IPerson, Person} from './model/person.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'my-app';
  names?: string;
  person?: IPerson;

  save() {
    console.log('::::::' + this.person.name);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.person = new Person();
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is `person.model.ts`:

```
export interface IPerson {
  name?: string;
}

export class Person implements IPerson {
  constructor(
    public name?: string
  ) {
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-error-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-inpu/61123200#61123200

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your ng-model binding has to be a two-way binding like so:
(notice the extra parentheses)

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name">
```

Comment: These kind of problems are the worst. Glad I could help.

Comment: This is quite embarrassing, Thank you. It saved my time

Answer (score 0):

You can look here :https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

in your case you can correct the code of `app.component.html` in this way :

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name">
    <button (click)="save()">save</button>
</form>
```