# Angular 4 - Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("

Tags: angular

below is the code snippet, i am getting above error
even after importing Formmodule, its not resolving

## app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import{firstComponent} from './first/first.component';

import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    firstComponent,
    SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule
  ],

Sec.component.html
==================

<input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="TwoWayData" [value]="TwoWayData" name=""  >
{{TwoWayData}}
```

## Sec.component.ts

```
TwoWayData:string='Fortune';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular error: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-error-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-inpu)

Comment: It's `ngModel`, not `ngmodel`. Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here, in [(ngmodel)] M is capital

```
[(ngmodel)]="TwoWayData"
```

Replace It

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="TwoWayData" [value]="TwoWayData" name="">
```

{{TwoWayData}}