# ion-range two-way binding not working in Ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to figure out how to data-bind an ion-range in ionic v4. The usage guide for v4 is light on info and I keep getting an error that reads, "can't bind to ngmodel since it isn't a known property of ion-range".

**Example from ionic v3 documentation**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range [(ngModel)]="brightness">
    <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Do you have the Angular `FormsModule` imported in the right module?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't imported the FormsModule, this needs to be imported in the same module where the code is (e.g. app.module or page.module if lazy loaded)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments section - the `FormsModule` had not been imported correctly. More discussion on how to import in:
[Angular error: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-error-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-inpu/43298039#43298039)