# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

Full code is:

```
 <input #inputSearch tabindex="0" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keydown.enter)="searchByClick()" type="text">
```

**app.module is:**

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [],
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
)}
export class AppModule {}
```

What is wrong, why it does not work for me?

Comment: can you paste your .ts fiile?

Comment: No, as you can see I have already applied in my code

Comment: You need to import `FormsModule`. You can find more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298039/2959415

Comment: I have tried impoer FormsModule, see my question again

Comment: @OPV sorry, but I don't see `FormsModule` in the listing of your AppModule's imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`
`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";` Import FormsModule & NgModule  in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Add this module to your:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [],
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
)}
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: No effect, I have found some the same question, I tested solutioins, no reslt

Comment: so paste your ts pls or we cannot understand why

Comment: Works like this `(ngModel)` but not `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Which ts? Compoenent or module?

Comment: .ts i mean app component.ts